# iOS XCTests - how to verify checkbox button is checked or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, ui-automation

I am trying to verify if a checkbox is checked or not for my XCTests code.
I see that the checkbox is checked in UI but my code returns "NO"
Help is appreciated. Below is my code

```
XCUIElement *checkBox = [[[[textField childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther] elementBoundByIndex:1] childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeButton] elementBoundByIndex:1];

BOOL isChecked = checkBox.isSelected;
```

isChecked returns "NO" even when checkbox is selected

Comment: Are you using a `UIButton` to serve as a checkbox,? Or are you using the iOS standard control for this, a `UISwitch`? I would recommend using a UISwitch on iOS.  Check boxes are not a common paradigm on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `isSelected` attribute is for use with accessibility.  It does not indicate whether the checkbox is checked. It basically returns whether the control is currently selected when Accessibility is turned on (e.g. for visually impared users where iOS will select controls on the screen and read them to the user).

It appears you have made your own check box using a `UIButton` to provide checkbox-like functionality.  If you have created your own custom control to toggle a UIButton's state, you would also have to have implemented a way to store the selection state.  Without seeing the rest of your implementation, there's no way for any of us to know how to get the state.

I would recommend using the `UISwitch` control which provides the functionality you desire in a native, consistent way.  If you do, it would be a simple test:

```
BOOL isChecked = [switch isOn];
```

Answer (score 1):

Been a while since I played with XCTests, but I think I used something like `[checkBox.value boolValue]`.